# How is possible to click on null item in ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, android-2.3-gingerbread

I got strange NullPointerException in Crashlytics from some users.

I have Adapter, which is implemented from BaseAdapter:

```
abstract public class BaseListAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter {
    private final ArrayList<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();

    ....

    @Override
    public T getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    ....
}
```

And concrete class:

```
class MessagesAdapter extends BaseListAdapter<MessagesListItem> {

    ....

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null)
            view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.message_listitem, null);

        MessagesListItem item = getItem(position);

        NetworkImageView avatar = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_listitem_avatar);
        ImageView online = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_listitem_online);
        TextView nick = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_listitem_nick);
        TextView preview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_listitem_preview);
        TextView unread = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_listitem_unread);

        avatar.setImageUrl(item.userAvatar, MyApp.getInstance().getImageLoader());
        online.setVisibility(item.userOnline? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        nick.setText(String.format("%s, %d", item.userNick, item.userAge));
        preview.setText(item.preview);
        unread.setText(String.valueOf(item.unread));
        unread.setVisibility(item.unread == 0? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

        return view;
    }

    ....
}
```

As you see if I put null into this adapter I for NullPointerException in getView(...) method. But I don't

I have ListView with attached instanced form this concrete class. And I have implemented OnItemClickListener:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Adapter adapter = parent.getAdapter();
    MessagesListItem messagesListItem = (MessagesListItem) adapter.getItem(position);
    User user = messagesListItem.getUser(); //<-- I got NullPointerException here

    ....
}
```

How could this happen? This adapter is wrapped into `HeaderViewListAdapter`, but I don't get any class cast exception. Also I didn't get null pointer in getView(). Just on this method.

I see, this issue happen only in android 2. I tried everything and don't reproduce this, bust users still got.

What I miss? Have anyone idea how fix? Or how to determine/reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By introducing a header or footer into your list view, you're changing the positions of your objects.

That is, if you have 1 header view, `adapter.getItem(0)` will return the object you used in `listView.addHeaderView(view, object, isSelectable)`. If you're only using `listView.addHeader(view)`, then object is null and isSelectable is true.

You can either compare the position in the onItemClick listener to known header / footer positions, or call `listView.addHeaderView(view, null, false)`, which will also disable the select & touch states for the header view.

The position in your adapter isn't effected (0 is still the first item in your list) because the wrapping adapter adjusts the position: line ~175 @ https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.java

Comment: I already used `listView.addHeaderView(view, null, false)` but somehow user still able to click on header. Maybe this is a bug from android.

Comment: Do you have any footers using just addFooterView(view)? Otherwise, is it possible that you are changing the list backing the array without calling notifyDataSetChanged (orInvalidated)

Comment: I did same with footer. I don't think about your next quess, because `ArrayList` newer threw out of boundaries exception or `getView()` throw null pointer, but whole time I got only in `OnItemClickListener`.